# "Unable to play video, Sorry this video cannot be played" when trying to display video from camera intent

Tags: android, android-intent, video

I am having a weird problem. (I am new to android) In my app I have an intent to launch the video camera as well as one to launch the camera.  Now what seems to happen is when I click on the image button to display image, it then display the images.  But when trying to display video it says "unable to play video". So I thought there was something wrong with my phone so I restarted my phone and it then seemed to play.  So when testing again it doesn't.

So I know there is nothing wrong with my code, but can't seem to display the video after it has been taken.  (and only plays after a reboot of the device)

Could someone please help me?

Thanks

**EDIT**

To take the video I use:

```
Intent imageIntent = new Intent    (android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy_HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
    File videosFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Cool Videos");
    videosFolder.mkdirs();
    image = new File(imagesFolder.getPath(), "Cvidoes_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
    fUri = Uri.fromFile(image);

    imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    startActivityForResult(imageIntent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

And then in my "display full screen"

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(temp_file),getMimeType(temp_file.getAbsolutePath()));
      startActivity(intent);
```

But the weird thing is worked before I recently updated to android version 5.0.

**EDIT** 2

Okay I have solved the issue.

I have pretty much nothing in my "OnActivityResult" section,  but added this and all is working again:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
              getApplicationContext(),
              new String[]{image.getAbsolutePath()},
              null,
              new OnScanCompletedListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.v("VideoScan",
                          "file " + path + " was scanned seccessfully: " + uri);
                 }
              });
```

So why since the update it stopped working and now have to add this?

Comment: We need a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You may think that there is nothing wrong with your code, but you may be mistaken.

Comment: Thanks, but have updated my question with the code I am using and a fix that seems to be working now.

Comment: Just shows... do a bit more research before asking questions :-)

Answer (score 0):

> So why since the update it stopped working and now have to add this?

Strictly speaking, we can't really answer this definitively.

What you added was code to arrange to have your video be indexed by the `MediaStore`. A video player receiving a `file:///` `Uri` — as you are using in your `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` — should not really care about `MediaStore`. Apparently, yours does, or does after your device was upgraded to Android 5.0. IMHO, that's a bug in the video player.

Now, in general, if you want the user to be able to work with the video separately from your app, you need to get it indexed by the `MediaStore`. That will happen automatically... eventually. Your code addition makes it happen much more quickly, which is generally a good idea.

So, I'd look at it more that you tripped over a bug in the video player, whose fix happened to be some code that you probably needed anyway.

In other words, it's just another day at the office... :-)